# How to put text next to each other from mysqli query

Tags: php, html, css

I am not even sure how to explain, so I ill just attach some pictures. Basically I have a couple of names in my DB and i am trying to display a list of them, but i would like to have 2 columns next to each other. What it does now -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ev3V.jpg and i need it to do. -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/90sFY.jpg

I am not really sure how to do this. Code I have:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
         <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 headx">
                    <h3>Bosses</h3>
         </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
                <?php while ($bosses = mysqli_fetch_assoc($kat_query)) {  ?>

                <a href="boss.php?id=<?php echo $bosses['id']; ?>"><?=$bosses['name']?></a><br />

                <?php } ?>

       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split code in two `col-md-6`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 headx">
            <h3>Bosses</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php while ($boss = mysqli_fetch_assoc($kat_query)) { ?>   
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
        <a href="boss.php?id=<?php echo $boss['id'];?>"><?php echo $boss['name']; ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php $boss = mysqli_fetch_assoc($kat_query); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
        <a href="boss.php?id=<?php echo $boss['id'];?>"><?php echo $boss['name']; ?></a>
    </div>
</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It is almost perfect, but still a little bit off https://imgur.com/dBg1vgz

Comment: can you share generate html?

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/n67XM4PE this is the whole file.

Comment: @MarekLanger Please accept the answer and vote up :)

Comment: Ok now it makes 2 columns, but of same names. And for some reason it does not show all of them, I got 5 in DB shows just 2x2

Comment: Ur a GOD THANK you very very much.